# How to mount HostPath Volume in Kubernetes with SELinux

Tags: docker, kubernetes, rhel, selinux

I am trying to mount a [hostPath volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath) into a Kubernetes Pod.  An example of a `hostPath` volume specification is shown below, which is taken from the docs.  I am deploying to hosts that are running RHEL 7 with SELinux enabled.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pd
spec:
  containers:
  - image: k8s.gcr.io/test-webserver
    name: test-container
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /test-pd
      name: test-volume
  volumes:
  - name: test-volume
    hostPath:
      # directory location on host
      path: /data
      # this field is optional
      type: Directory
```

When my Pod tries to read from a file that has been mounted from the underlying host, I get a "Permission Denied" error.  When I run `setenforce 0` to turn off SELinux, the error goes away and I can access the file.  I get the same error when I bind mount a directory into a Docker container.

The issue is described [here](https://www.projectatomic.io/blog/2015/06/using-volumes-with-docker-can-cause-problems-with-selinux/) and, when using Docker, can be fixed by using the `z` or `Z` bind mount flag, described in the Docker docs [here](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/#configure-the-selinux-label).

Whilst I can fix the issue by running

```
chcon -Rt svirt_sandbox_file_t /path/to/my/host/dir/to/mount
```

I see this as a nasty hack, as I need to do this on every host in my Kubernetes cluster and also because my deployment of Kubernetes as described in the YAML spec is not a complete description of what it is that needs to be done to get my YAML to run correctly.  Turning off SELinux is not an option.

I can see that Kubernetes mentions SELinux security contexts in the docs [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/), but I haven't been able to successfully mount a hostPath volume into a pod without getting the permission denied error.

What does the YAML need to look like to successfully enable a container to mount a HostPath volume from an underlying host that is running SELinux?

**Update:**

The file I am accessing is a CA certificate that has these labels:

```
system_u:object_r:cert_t:s0
```

When I use the following options:

```
securityContext:
  seLinuxOptions:
    level: "s0:c123,c456"
```

and then check the access control audit errors via `ausearch -m avc -ts recent`, I can see that there is a permission denied error where the container has a level label of `s0:c123,c456`, so I can see that the level label works.  I have set the label to be `s0`.

However, if I try to change the `type` label to be `cert_t`, the container doesn't even start, there's an error :

```
container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:364: container init caused \"write /proc/self/task/1/attr/exec: invalid argument\""
```

I don't seem to be able to change the type label of the container.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign SELinux labels using `seLinuxOptions`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pd
spec:
  containers:
  - image: k8s.gcr.io/test-webserver
    name: test-container
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /test-pd
      name: test-volume
    securityContext:
      seLinuxOptions: # it may don’t have the desired effect
        level: "s0:c123,c456"
  securityContext:
    seLinuxOptions:
      level: "s0:c123,c456"
  volumes:
  - name: test-volume
    hostPath:
      # directory location on host
      path: /data
      # this field is optional
      type: Directory
```

According to [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/):

Thanks to [Phil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1020315/phil) for pointing that out. It appears to be working only in `Pod.spec.securityContext` according to the [issue comment](https://github.com/projectatomic/adb-atomic-developer-bundle/issues/117#issuecomment-215313573)

- **seLinuxOptions**: Volumes that support SELinux labeling are relabeled to be accessible by the label specified under seLinuxOptions. Usually you only need to set the level section. This sets the Multi-Category Security (MCS) label **given to all Containers in the Pod as well as the Volumes**.

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I get a `Permission denied` error that is attributable to SELinux.  Is there something else that needs to be configured in order to make this work?

Comment: This sets the SELinux context level. But I have not been able to extend this solution to also include `seLinuxOptions.type`. While the container process correctly assumes this `type`. Volumes are not relabeled with this type.

Comment: I've provided [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63515340/1020315) that describes this in a bit more detail

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on [the answer from VAS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51026623/1020315) as it is partially correct:

**You can only specify the level portion of an SELinux label** when relabeling a path destination pointed to by a `hostPath` volume. This is automatically done so by the `seLinuxOptions.level` attribute specified in your `securityContext`.

However attributes such as `seLinuxOptions.type` currently have no effect on volume relabeling. As of this writing, this is still an [open issue within Kubernetes](https://github.com/projectatomic/adb-atomic-developer-bundle/issues/117)

Answer (score 0):

You could try with full permissions:

```
 ...
 image: k8s.gcr.io/test-webserver
 securityContext:
   privileged: true
 ...
```

Comment: This does work, thanks, but it now involves forcing my container to run as a privileged container, which is pretty far from ideal, in terms of security.  Is there not an option around `seLinuxOptions` that can be made to work without making the container privileged?

Comment: yeah, I know. I believe that's something with SELinux configuration. Are you taking into account the following restriction?: `Note: To assign SELinux labels, the SELinux security module must be loaded on the host operating system.
`

Comment: Yes - so if I set a `level` within `seLinuxOptions` and look at the access errors via `ausearch -m abc -ts recent`, I can see that I can change the level of the container, but I cannot seem to change the `type` of the container. I think I need to do both to get access.

Comment: @John I see something similar (if not identical) to your observation, which is that while I can get my container to run under a specific SELinux type. The volumes I mount are not relabeled to this type. This makes a bit of sense looking at it now, since these will be process types and not file types.

Answer (score 0):

Using selinux can solve this problem. Reference article:
*https://zhimin-wen.medium.com/selinux-policy-for-openshift-containers-40baa1c86aa5*

In addition: You can refer to the selinux parameters to set the addition, deletion, and modification of the mount directory
*https://selinuxproject.org/page /ObjectClassesPerms*

my setting：

If a directory's selinux is unconfined_u:object_r:kubernetes_file_t:s0 , you kan defind a selinux policy is:

```
module myapp 1.0;

require {
 type kubernetes_file_t;
 type container_t;
 class file { create open read unlink write getattr execute setattr link };
 class dir { add_name create read remove_name write };
}

#============= container_t ==============

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow container_t kubernetes_file_t:dir { add_name create read remove_name write };

#!!!! This avc is allowed in the current policy
allow container_t kubernetes_file_t:file { create open read unlink write getattr execute setattr link };
```

run command on node:

```
sudo checkmodule -M -m -o myapp.mod myapp.te
sudo semodule_package -o myapp.pp -m myapp.mod
sudo semodule -i myapp.pp
```