# Kubernetes Pod permission denied on local volume

Tags: kubernetes

I have created a pod on Kubernetes and mounted a local volume but when I try to execute the ls command on locally mounted volume, I get a permission denied error. If I disable SELINUX then everything works fine. I am unable to make out how do I make it work with SELinux enabled.

#### Following is the output of permission denied:

```
kubectl apply -f testpod.yaml
root@olcne-operator-ol8 opc]# kubectl get all
NAME            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/testpod     1/1     Running   0          5s
# kubectl exec -i -t testpod /bin/bash
kubectl exec [POD] [COMMAND] is DEPRECATED and will be removed in a future version. Use kubectl exec [POD] -- [COMMAND] instead.
[root@testpod /]# cd /u01
[root@testpod u01]# ls
ls: cannot open directory '.': Permission denied
[root@testpod u01]#
```

#### Following is the testpod.yaml

```
cat testpod.yaml
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: testpod
  labels:
    name: testpod
spec:
  hostname: testpod
  restartPolicy: Never
  volumes:
    - name: swvol
      hostPath:
        path: /u01
  containers:
    - name: testpod
      image: oraclelinux:8
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      securityContext:
       privileged: false
      command: [/usr/sbin/init]
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: "/u01"
        name: swvol
```

#### Selinux Configuration on worker node:

```
# sestatus
SELinux status:                 enabled
SELinuxfs mount:                /sys/fs/selinux
SELinux root directory:         /etc/selinux
Loaded policy name:             targeted
Current mode:                   enforcing
Mode from config file:          enforcing
Policy MLS status:              enabled
Policy deny_unknown status:     allowed
Memory protection checking:     actual (secure)
Max kernel policy version:      31

---
# semanage fcontext -l  | grep kub | grep container_file
/var/lib/kubelet/pods(/.*)?                        all files          system_u:object_r:container_file_t:s0
/var/lib/kubernetes/pods(/.*)?                     all files          system_u:object_r:container_file_t:s0
```

#### Machine OS Details

```
 rpm -qa | grep kube
kubectl-1.20.6-2.el8.x86_64
kubernetes-cni-0.8.1-1.el8.x86_64
kubeadm-1.20.6-2.el8.x86_64
kubelet-1.20.6-2.el8.x86_64
kubernetes-cni-plugins-0.9.1-1.el8.x86_64

----
cat /etc/oracle-release
Oracle Linux Server release 8.4

---
uname -r
5.4.17-2102.203.6.el8uek.x86_64
```

Comment: Hello @drifter Please look at the answers for the same issue on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51000791/how-to-mount-hostpath-volume-in-kubernetes-with-selinux).

Comment: Hi, It worked for me, and thanks for sharing the info.

Answer (score 1):

*This is a community wiki answer posted for better visibility. Feel free to expand it.*

SELinux labels can be assigned with `seLinuxOptions`:

```
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: testpod
  labels:
    name: testpod
spec:
  hostname: testpod
  restartPolicy: Never
  volumes:
    - name: swvol
      hostPath:
        path: /u01
  containers:
    - name: testpod
      image: oraclelinux:8
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      command: [/usr/sbin/init]
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: "/u01"
        name: swvol
  securityContext:
    seLinuxOptions:
      level: "s0:c123,c456"
```

From the [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/#discussion):

> `seLinuxOptions`: Volumes that support SELinux labeling are relabeled
> to be accessible by the label specified under `seLinuxOptions`.
> Usually you only need to set the `level` section. This sets the
> Multi-Category Security (MCS) label given to all Containers in the Pod
> as well as the Volumes.

Based on the information from the [original post on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51000791/how-to-mount-hostpath-volume-in-kubernetes-with-selinux):

> **You can only specify the level portion of an SELinux label** when relabeling a path destination pointed to by a `hostPath` volume. This
> is automatically done so by the `seLinuxOptions.level` attribute
> specified in your `securityContext`.
>
> However attributes such as `seLinuxOptions.type` currently have no
> effect on volume relabeling. As of this writing, this is still an
> [open issue within
> Kubernetes](https://github.com/projectatomic/adb-atomic-developer-bundle/issues/117)

Comment: @Andrew, I tested with seLinuxOptions, and I did not find a better way to handle assigning a type to volume such as I tried ```type: container_t``` and I did not see volumes are labeled with ```container_t```.  I think it is expected as per your update.  However, I am still struggling to assign multiple contexts to a directory because library loading in my case is failing and I need to assign more context. Also, there is no way to run chcon from inside the non-priv container.

Comment: In case of any updates from your side regarding the initial question, you can change community wiki answer. For other problems it would be better to create separate questions.